# Two way or One way repeated measures Anova

Tags: repeated-measures, manova

I want to examine the effect of gender on running conditions.

There are 4 running conditions including baseline and i want to see if there is a significant difference between genders across these four conditions.

Would I use a two way or one way repeated measures anova??
thanks

Comment: HI Clara, welcome to CrossValidated. I think we need more information about what you want to test. Do you think that the effect of gender will differ across running conditions? Was it the same people in each running condition, or different people.  Do you just want to test the overall difference in gender?

Comment: "Repeated measures" can mean different things to different people. Can you explain explicitly how your repeated measures design and two-way design differ?